# OracleCommandBuilder - parameters named after columns instead of :p1, :p2, etc.?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm using an OracleCommandBuilder to autogenerate SQL based on a SELECT statement.  The parameters in the generated UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements take the form :p1, :p2, and so forth.

In the course of researching how to use the OracleCommandBuilder, I could swear that somewhere I ran across a property I could set, or *something* I could do to get the parameters to mirror the column names, so a LASTNAME column would have a :LASTNAME parameter generated.

But now I can't figure out how to do it.  Has anyone heard of such a setting, or did I imagine it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh geez, there it is.

[GetInsertCommand(bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h39hb8e.aspx) (and similarly for GetUpdateCommand and GetDeleteCommand)

I didn't realize there were overloads of these.

Comment: Strangely, though, it generates parameters named without the colon in front: "LASTNAME" instead of ":LASTNAME".  Is that a problem?  If not, what is the colon for?

Comment: Ah, here we go:  "When using named parameters in an SQL statement called by an OracleCommand of CommandType.Text, you must precede the parameter name with a colon (:). However, in a stored procedure, or when referring to a named parameter elsewhere in your code (for example, when adding OracleParameter objects to the Parameters property), do not precede the named parameter with a colon (:). The .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle supplies the colon automatically."